# Firebase Remote Config - Conditions not applied

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-remote-config

I am using the Firebase Web SDK 8.3.1 and I have created a remote config parameter with conditions based on a custom user properties.

The problem I encounter is that my end users always get the default value, never one from any of the conditions, even if I am sure the user actually matches the conditions...

I see in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/config-analytics#remote_config_and_user_properties):

> Warning: To use audiences and user properties with Remote Config, you
> must enable Google Analytics data sharing for your project. In your
> app, you'll need to ensure Firebase Analytics is present and data
> collection is available as well.

Then if I follow the provided [link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6383877#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) I see the instructions:

> To manage Google Analytics for Firebase data sharing:
>
> 1. Sign in to Firebase and select a project.
> 2. Click the Settings icon and select Project Settings.
> 3. On the Project Settings page, click Data privacy.
> 4. See the options available under Google Analytics data
>    sharing. When you share Analytics data, you share it for all the apps
>    in your project.
>
> Turn on the switch for Share Analytics data with all Firebase
> features, including Predictions, A/B Testing, Remote Config, and
> Notifications (this is your default setting) to enable all current
> options to share data with Firebase features.

But in my firebase console I dont have this switch! Under "Google Analytics data sharing" there is now another link:

[image]

So I cant turn on this setting :(

Note: how I made sure my user actually matches the condition "user property X == A":

- Wait 30mins
- Launch the app with a user having user property X set to A
- Launch the Realtime dashboard of Firebase Analytics and filter to the last 30mins
- And here I see that there were indeed 1 user in the last 30mins and this user had property X set to A

So is there anything special I should do when I want to create a condition using custom user properties?

Comment: I am having same issue, and I verified exactly like you. I assigned group property to user, let say group superuser, and I saw that value correctly in real time view. But remote config property says 0% user match this condition group = superuser....

Comment: Did you manage to solve your own issue ?

Comment: Same here. Did either of you solve the issue? @KristiJorgji

Comment: @Aegir no I just gave up on firebaseremoteconfig and created my own api with conditions and insights

Comment: Ok thanks, In my case it was because of a dexguard/proguard issue.